# google api using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

```js
var map;

 function initMap() {
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: {
       lat: 30.3434,
       lng: 30.234
     },
     zoom: 8
   });
 }
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

how to input coordinates to google api java script automatically ?! 
here is the code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat:30.3434, lng:30.234},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

i want to the "center" to take the coordinates from a txt file at my pc at as a test

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you willing to know where you should write your coordinates?

Comment: by automatically you mean **dynamically** right ?

Comment: So do you know how to load a file?

Comment: Or do you want to get the user's coordinates automatically?

Comment: It's unclear bro, try to detail it better

Comment: sorry for my english :) , i don't know how to load a file , i want it to copy  coordinates from a txt file dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is `location.txt` and the content is something like:
`lat;long`, e.g. `30.3434;30.234`

You can do what you want using jQuery:

```
function initMap() {
    var myLat, myLng, myMap;
    $.ajax({
        url : "location.txt",
        dataType: "text",
        success : function (data) {
             var location = data.split(";");
             myLat=location[0]; 
             myLng=location[1]
        },
        error: function(data) {
             console.log("unable to retrieve data from location.txt")
        },
        complete: function(data) {
           //Called after success and error callbacks are executed.
          myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat:myLat, lng:myLng},
              zoom: 8
          });  
        }
    });
}
```